# resolve promise on socket.write when error (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, error-handling, promise

I have problem how to `resolve` the promise on `send()` function, if `socket.write()`resulting in an error, nodejs **socket does not throw exception** when write operation is error

while I still got notified from `this.socket.on('error',..)` callback if there are an error while I write to the socket, but still I can't resolve the promise, so the call to `send()` was stuck

what i want is, user can just use the `send().then((result) => {})`, and if there are error, they can read it on `result` argument

```
socket.on('error',(err) => {
    console.error(err); //if there are error this will be called
});

async send(data){
    return new Promise(resolve, () => {
        try{
            socket.write(data, 'binary',() => {
                resolve(true); //data sent, resolve the promise
            });
        }
        catch(e){ //nodejs socket.write does not throw exception
            resolve(false);
        }
    })
}

//call send, and wait for results
send({..}).then((result) => {
    if(result === true){
         //send success
    }
    else {
         //send failed
    }
});
```

this one works as expected, when there are error, promise still resolved

```
async send(data){
    return new Promise(resolve, () => {
        try{
            let errorHandler = (err) => {
                resolve(false);
            }
            socket.once('error', errorHandler);
            socket.write(data, 'binary',() => {
                socket.off('error', errorHandler);
                resolve(true); //data sent, resolve the promise
            });
        }
        catch(e){ //nodejs socket.write does not throw exception
            resolve(false);
        }
    })
}
```

but, **is there any better solution?**, because i don't want create anonymous function and to call `on('error',)` and `off('error',)` everytime `send()` function is invoked

Comment: Using `once` is a good idea.  But what you should be doing is calling reject, not resolve..  Also get rid of the try catch.  You could also remove the `async` as it's not doing anything.

Comment: Isn't throwing an exception on your `on('error')` an option?

Comment: i know about reject, its just same idea, if i use reject i can catch on `then` later, but i can also using `resolve` and check resolve argument if there are error or not, its not **the problem**, the problem is `socket.write` only notify error using `socket.on('error',)` not directly on `socket.write` call

Comment: @astorga, throwing exception on `on('error')` is good idea, but i need  to handle the exception throwed on the rest of the codes, not just on this specific socket write error. and also i bit worried if error handler throwing another exceptions

Comment: @uray you can `.catch()` after `.then()` body.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `error` argument passed in `socket.write` callback.

```
        socket.write(data, 'binary',(err) => {
            if (err) return reject err;
            resolve(true); //data sent, resolve the promise
        });
```

But it is recommended to listen on `error` event.

Source:

> The writable.write() method writes some data to the stream, and calls the supplied callback once the data has been fully handled. If an error occurs, the callback may or may not be called with the error as its first argument. To reliably detect write errors, add a listener for the 'error' event.

-- From [Writable.write() doc](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback)

Comment: if this is true, i don't see any documentation of callback argument specification on `socket.write()`, where did u see it? , and also if I check by `write` on disconnected socket, the callback was never called, it just invoke `socket.on('error')` handler

Comment: @uray The docs mention "See Writable stream write() method for more information." I updated the answer to reflect the source.

Comment: and it said, "the callback may **or may not** be called with the error as its first argument"

Comment: Right, that's true. It's not reliable, as mentioned in my answer. Listening to `error` event is reliable. What is your doubt here?